# when creating RPM package, how to auto install dependencies

Tags: rpm, rpmbuild, rpm-spec

My program is basically a C-based MySQL server, it needs gcc, mysql-server, mysql-devel in order to run successfully.

Now I have to pack the program into RPM package, and it should be able to auto install the dependencies so that the RPM package can be installed on a clean RHEL machine, and the program can run instantly after the installation.

Problem is if I write the below script in SPEC file %pre section, it gets stuck during "transaction".

```
sudo yum groupinstall "Development Tools" -y
sudo yum install mysql-server mysql-client -y
```

It seems you can't use another rpm installation tool in SPEC file.

How do I do this?

Comment: If the supporting stuff is just standard packages from the standard repos, shouldn't them being marked as a dependency be enough for rpm or yum or whatever to install them?

Comment: I tried to mark the dependencies in "Requires" field, but rpm -i will fail, with error saying "required package not installed" or something similar, but I forgot to test with the yum command. will try again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't do it directly, you cannot install another RPM from within your RPM spec file.

The normal way, which you should follow, is to make your RPM depends on the other RPMs it needs, e.g. by adding this to your .spec file:

```
 Requires:  gcc, mysql-server, mysql-devel
```

When you then try to install your rpm with the rpm command:

```
rpm -ivh yourrpm-1.0.0.rpm
```

it will fail and tell you which packages to install, and you have to install those packages manually first.

Or you can use yum to install your rpm file:

```
 yum install ./yourrpm.1.0.0.rpm
```

and yum will download and install the required dependencies before it installs your RPM package.

Comment: Thanks! I tried to mark the dependencies in "Requires" field, rpm -i will fail like you said, with error saying "required package not installed" or something similar, what I need is that user doesn't have to manually install all the dependencies one by one. I forgot to test with the yum command though, It looks super promising.

Comment: Hi, I tried the "yum install " command, seems like it ignored the %build and %install section. I did "make" in %build section, and copy the binary to a specific location in %install section.

Comment: @xmanreturn First you need to create your rpm package using the rpmbuild command, this runs the stuff in your %build and %install sections. You do that once to create an rpm package that you then install using the rpm or yum command. The %install and %build section are only for creating the rpm package, they are not performed when you install the rpm package.

Answer (score 0):

Yes: there is an exclusive rpmdb lock held while installing preventing all attempts to use rpm from within a package script.

Usually what is done is create a custom yum repository and invoke yum.

Otherwise create a short shell script that invokes rpm/yum to automate your install.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but the short shell script still needs to be invoked somewhere in SPEC file? probably in %pre section?

Comment: I was suggesting a short shell script to invoke rpm multiple times, not a script to be run by rpm: you cannot access an rpmdb from scripts run by rpm itself.

Comment: I understand, but I have to install the dependencies within the rpm installation process, I got only one shot..

Comment: There is a way around the locking, but it is a gross hack. The file lock is instantiated on /var/lib/rpm/rpm.lock. Rename that file, run rpm in the scriptlet, rename the file back in place. Known to "work", but YMMV: if it breaks, you get to keep all the pieces ;-)